# how can i able to video call with using QuickBox when app is background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, quickblox

I have try set background mode like[image]

Status bar in seeing red color but not get any video call.

So please help me how to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of long-running tasks permitted in the background in [Apple's documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1%20)

Camera access is not one of them. You will need to have your app in the foreground to use the camera.